# .NET 4.6.1 and IIS7 - Cannot upload large files from WebAPI2 endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am trying to upload files using my .NET application. I cannot upload large files and it responds with 413 - Request Entity Too Large.

I tried solutions that suggested changing `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength` in web.config. Also changed the `uploadReadAhead` setting in IIS. I still am unable to upload the files.

The project has two web configs. Parent directory web config has the following settings:

```
<system.web>
...other lines
        <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="999999" />
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

The web config in the inner Portal directory has:

```
<system.web>
...other lines
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="999999" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
...other lines
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="999999" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.webServer>
```

How do I fix this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum, that should be fine. On the other hand, seems to me that adopting some kind of nice up-loading library that up-loads in chunks would be better. This tends to "less freeze up" the user interface and also tends to not freeze up the web server either.

I mean, for a user to up-load a big file, then they are going to be stuck watching the screen - nothing occuring. With a nice up-loader library, then only small chunks are sent up, you get a progess bar, and you have un-limited up-load file sizes.

However, you could try in the main web.config,

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2048000000"/>
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

So, you could try adding above under system.webServer